# How to config geoserver to read style of vector layer from postgis/SQL store?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, vector, style

I've imported vector layers from map info pro to both SQL server and post gis using easy loader.
In both cases I've included style column in the exported table.
When I create new store in geoserver and see the list of layers , each layer has the mi_style column in the list of features at the bottom of the screen . But when I publish the layer it still have the default style of geoserver . How can I set it to read the style from the column ?

Comment: The mi_style column is only for MapInfo use, I don't think GeoServer will know what to do with it.

Comment: Maybe there is option to create sld from it ?

Comment: I have never heard of a way, but happy to be proven wrong.